# Saving objects' coordinates as RGBA

Tags: texturing, scripting, coordinates, texture-coordinates

I need to save multiple objects' location in XYZ as RGBA data on an image. The colors should match that of blender in metric, so if I move the object up 105.4 centimeters in blender, the color should be 1.054. Just like shown here. And even go in the negatives, like the blue.
[image]

Furthermore I need to save their rotation in quaternions as RGBA as well, different image though.

I've found this script, but it doesn't do exactly as I need, could it be rewritten, or how would I go about it?

Since I also need the data from multiple objects, saved in a string of pixels.
https://github.com/JoshRBogart/unreal_tools?files=1

For a visual representation of what I need to do, I need to place these track elements (shown in green outline) in a shape to form the belt for a tracked machine. Each pixel corresponds to one element and it's position/rotation. So the number of pixels should match the number of objects.
[image]

The rest will then be handled by the shader in the game.

I've included an original file from the game, if it helps.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/amvvysvzrba3w9f/trackArray.rar?dl=0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would basically do

```py
def locations_to_image(objects, image_name='Locations'):
    im = bpy.data.images.new(image_name, len(objects), 1)
    i = 0
    for ob in objects:
        im.pixels[i:i+3] = xyz_to_rgb(ob.matrix_world.translation)
        i += 4
    return im

def xyz_to_rgb(xyz):
    # Replace with however you want locations encoded.
    # This is just an example.
    bb_max = 50  # bounding box size
    return [(v + bb_max)/(2*bb_max) for v in xyz]
```

Edit to match your specifications.

PS. RGBA components are always in the range [0,1], so you'll need to encode them somehow.